# How to distingiush adaptable from adaptive?

Tags: vocabulary

I really wonder what is the subtle difference between these two terms, and if they could be used interchangably somewhere?

Adaptable

Adaptive

Comment: Hi, Alex, **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance. Can you show us some examples where you found these two words confusing?

Comment: First thanks for your reply. It is just a question turning in my mind. I have never seen anywhere those words

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two words mean different things.  *Adaptive* has the suffix *ive*, which comes to us from the Latin form *-ivus* and which adds the sense of "characteristic of" to a verb.  So when we say something is adaptive, we mean it may be characterized by or described as adapting.  From [*The Works of Charles Darwin*](https://books.google.com/books?id=6-YTCgAAQBAJ&pg=PP5&dq=%22adaptive%22%20darwin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjx8J3Jx7LKAhWH3SYKHTATDJk4ChDoAQhOMAk#v=onepage&q=%22adaptive%22%20darwin&f=false):

> [H]e [Darwin] was testing comparative survival and possible
>   **adaptive** values of the various forms produced by self fertilization
>   vis-à-vis cross fertilization.

*Adaptable*, on the other hand, has the suffix *-able*, which adds the meaning of capability to the verb, so something that's adaptable can adapt.  From *[Darwin](https://books.google.com/books?id=m5D7g4vMBg4C&pg=PA54&dq=%22adaptable%22%20darwin&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiy3JbryrLKAhUHWCYKHeCZAOUQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22adaptable%22%20darwin&f=false)* by W. Brown and A. Fabian:

> It is not the strongest of the species that survives, nor the most
>   intelligent that survives, it is the one that is most **adaptable** to
>   change.

The species here that are adaptable may also be characterized as adapting, so "adaptive to change" would be apt in the sentence above.  But note that the same substitution won't work in the first quote.  The adaptive values are the ones that adaptable species have, but the values themselves aren't capable of adaptation.  That process is reserved for species.